# CSS can't correctly align tabbed menu

Tags: css

Could you please help me to fix my menu in IE7.

The code is:

```
<ul id="layer1">
<li     id="current" >
  <span><a href="/">Главная</a></span>
</li>



#menu {
margin-left:150px;
}
#menu ul#layer1 {
list-style-image:none;
list-style-position:outside;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0 auto;
padding:0;
}
#menu ul#layer1 li {
background:transparent url(/site_media/images/left.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
float:left;
margin-left:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
padding-left:6px;
padding-top:4px;
}
#menu ul#layer1 li span {
background:transparent url(/site_media/images/right.jpg) no-repeat scroll right top;
margin-right:6px;
padding-bottom:6px;
padding-right:6px;
padding-top:4px;
}
#menu li a {
background-color:#BF1E2D;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:4px 35px 6px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#menu ul#layer1 li#current span {
background:transparent url(/site_media/images/right-gray.png) no-repeat scroll right top;
}
#menu ul#layer1 li#current {
background:transparent url(/site_media/images/left-gray.png) no-repeat scroll left top;
}
#menu ul#layer1 li#current a {
background-color:#E3E3E3;
color:#BF1E2D;
}
```

You also can see the site here http://j-in.org.ua:9000

Comment: That's not a question. Please tell us what your problem is. I couldn't see anything different in IE7 when comparing with Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for so quick answer: what I see in IE7 is
http://img.skitch.com/20090621-cxi22xbi6nfmp7d92g1xf9rh56.jpg

And it's broken :(

Comment: Which browsers does this work in?

Comment: Not easy to understand this problem, but try breaking this "background" monster down. background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image:url(".."); background-position:top right;

Answer (score 1):

Remove the top and bottom padding from the li and float the span left:

```
#menu ul#layer1 li{
    background: url(left.png) left top no-repeat; 
    margin-left:6px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    float: left;
}

#menu ul#layer1 li span{
    background: url(right.jpg) right top no-repeat;
    padding-right:6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    float:left;
}
```